# Антекты, с выводом анкет на отдельную страницу.

Tags: php, html, mysql

Доброго времени суток.
Не подскажите есть ли уже что-то готовое:
Человек оставляет анкету она выводится в список.
Админ потверждает или нет и это отображается в списке.
Зарание всем спасибо:)
Или на чём можно реализовать.

Comment: так вы же написали на чем ( метки ). Только вот админ часть это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: Даже можно так сказать, человек пишет заявку на администратора, админ потверждает или нет.

Comment: В админ части по идее кнопка лишь, просмотр списка и нажатие потвердить или отказать(причина) и пользовательский список чтобы все могли посмотреть заявки.

Есть одна идея реализации на одном движке, но у меня не срабатывает отправка почему-то :( я слаб в верстке...

Comment: Ну да, как сверстаете, так и отправится. Принимаются данные в $_POST,$_GET, делаете `var_dump($_POST,$_GET)`, смотрите что не доходит.

Comment: http://trat.red-shadow.ru/profiles_ajax_add.php вот по идее форма, как проверить что не работает и что куда отправляется:(?

http://www.overpro.ru/upload/uploads/Pomosch.zip Вот скрипт и что изменил и т.д. :( буду очень благодарен админ вход test 123123

Comment: ну судя по отсутствующему action у формы, на этот же файл и отправляются данные, открывайте его, тестируйте, я вам написал уже как. Кстати у `html`-страницы должны быть соответствующие теги, не только форма.

Comment: > Есть одна идея реализации на одном движке ...

Что за CMS? Самописная? Если нет, то вам будет очень сложно что-то сделать самому. И "*я слаб в верстке...*" - это тут ни при чем, а в php вы, как я понимаю, пока слабы.

Comment: когда говорят `free-lance` это имеется в виду что кто-то свободен и готов выполнить заказ... Хешкод не совсем для этого.

Comment: Тоесть либо платно, либо мне не сделать?